# $http get method fails even with valid json from .Net WebApi in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, .net, angularjs, json, asp.net-web-api

I am getting a valid JSON request but only $http fail method is invoked. It shows OK 200 in firebug. Also the view is not getting updated. Newbie trying out AngularJS so something could be too wrong :)

```
 $http.jsonp("http://localhost:51377/api/Books/1").success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("Suc");
        $scope.people = data;
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.people = data;
        alert("fail");
    });
```

This is the response in firebug:

```
{"ID":1,"BookName":"ASP.Net"}
```

Also fails for:

```
[{"ID":1,"BookName":"ASP.Net"}]
```

getting 404 in status code in `$http` call. I am using `jsonp` which should take care CORS? as I read from somewhere. My angular is in **file://** protocol

*Update-1:*
Tried with launching my angular in localhost from VS. Same results

*Update-2:*
I added configuration changes to remove CORS in my backend .net webapi and now it works with the following code but still the original above code using `jsonp` fails

```
        $http({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'http://localhost:51377/api/Books/',
        responseType: "json"
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        alert(data);
        console.log('Success: ' + data);
        $scope.people = data;
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('Error: ' + data);
    });
```

Comment: did you tried angular file putting in http protocol?

Comment: Did you try adding ?callback=JSON_CALLBACK (see my answer below)? It's in the angular docs. Also, this JSFiddle shows that it is required: http://jsfiddle.net/saarmstrong/hYACX/8/light/

Comment: @MarkWatson I will try that and update here.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add a callback parameter to your request:

```
$http.jsonp("http://localhost:51377/api/Books/1?callback=JSON_CALLBACK")
```

More info here:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http#jsonp

Also, see this JSFiddle (not mine):

http://jsfiddle.net/saarmstrong/hYACX/8/light/

When you remove the callback parameter it fails...

Answer (score 0):

try to use only "/api/Books/1" instead of "http://localhost:51377/api/Books/1"